# Segmentation Fault in a simple program

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, dynamic-programming

I have to submit some c++ code to a judge system which provides feedback.

However, I'm getting a segfault for the "hard testcases".

It would be really nice if someone could have a quick look at my code to help me out.

(the first input will always be a positive int)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long t;
    cin >> t;
    bool table[t][t];
    long long n = t;
    int sum = 0;
    long long s;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin >> table[t][t];
        if (!table[t][t])
        {
            sum++;
        }
    }
    for(t=0;t<n;t++)
    {
        for(s=t+1;s<n;s++)
        {
            table[t][s] = 
                    (table[t][s-1] && !table[s][s]) ||
                    (!table[t][s-1] && table[s][s]);
            if(!table[t][s])
            {
                    sum++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `bool table[t][t];` is not valid C++ since the value of `t` is not known at compile time. Did your compiler not report that as an error?

Comment: Well starting up the debugger and inspecting what's actually going wrong, should give you a better clue than asking here!

Comment: It did not, no. should i rather use malloc to dynamically create the array?

Comment: `no. should i rather use malloc` if you were programming in c yes not if you are using c++. The c++ answer is to use a std::vector.

Comment: For all the inputs which i provide, it workd fine. problem is that i don't know the input which is given by the judge..

Comment: `long long t;` I suspect that to allow values that are way larger than your stack.

Comment: @svince You actually should use `std::array` or even better `std::vector`, that syntax isn't standard.

Comment: it also segfault's when i'm using int.. i only put long long there in case the input was too big..

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Okay, thank you very much :) i will try to do it with std::vector

Comment: `it also segfault's when i'm using int..` That is still too big. Remember the stack size is a few MB. Not GBs.

Comment: I'm a c-programmer, and i'm really new to c++.. sorry guys

Comment: @drescherjm well then i don't think that this is the problem.. since this class is not really into stack frames and stuff like that.

Comment: VLAs are created on the stack. Say your stack is 8 MB you can not allocate an array that is larger (or even close to 8MB) and expect that to work.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any possibility indexes would go out of range so most probably "hard cases" have `t` big enough to overflow the stack, as you use non standard for C++ dynamic array. Allocate data for your array on heap using `std::vector`

```
vector<vector<bool>> table{ t, vector<bool>{ t } };

vector<vector<bool>> table( t, vector<bool>( t ) ); // if you do not have C++11 yet
```

Answer (score -1):

If I give input `t= 2` the value you are reading using `std::cin` would be `table[2][2]` which is invalid index hence raising segmentation fault. Max index in case of `t=2` would be `table[1][1]`.

Comment: Incorrect, `t` is used inside a loop where it is decremented

Comment: that is post-decrement,not pre-decrement. @Slava

Comment: In that context that does not matter for index (matters for loop logic). Think about this code: `int a = b++; int c = b;` if you change `b++` to `++b`, that only will affect `a` but not `c`.

Comment: My mistake. Apologies.

Comment: No need for apologies, everybody makes mistake :)